# how to number subgroups in a dataframe in R

Tags: r

I am struggling to number subgroups in a dataframe.

Let's take `iris` dataset for example.
Let's say that `iris$Species` identifies my subgroups (so I have three subgroups: `setosa`, `versicolor`, `virginica`). Now I would like to add another column to iris, let's say numer of observations: `iris$Obs`. And for each of the subgroups, I'd like to have numbers, from 1 to the length of a subgroup, that resets to 1 when the subgroup changes.

In other words, I'd like the "`Obs`" to start at 1 whenever "`Species`" changes and increment by one, as long as "`Species`" is the same.

I prepared an image, but being a complete noob I have no reputation points to paste it here...

Thank everyone for help!

EDIT: `> dput(iris)`

```
structure(list(Species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("setosa", 
"versicolor", "virginica"), class = "factor")), .Names = "Species", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) ave** Try `ave`:

```
transform(iris, Obs = ave(c(Species), Species, FUN = seq_along))
```

The first argument of `ave` can be anything as long as it is a numeric vector with one element per row.  For example, we could have used `1:nrow(iris)`, `numeric(nrow(iris))` or `Sepal.Length`.  In this case `Species` is a `"factor"` and `c(Species)` is `"numeric"`.   The rows of each group need not be contiguous.

**2) match**  Another possibility is this which subtracts the position of the first occurrence of each group from its sequence number and adds 1:

```
transform(iris, Obs = seq_along(Species) - match(Species, Species) + 1)
```

If the +1 is omitted the it will give numbers starting from 0 rather than 1.  This solution requires that the rows of each group be contiguous.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `getanID` from my "splitstackshape" package.

For what you describe, the code would be:

```
getanID(iris, "Species")
```

What it looks like where the group is changing:

```
getanID(iris, "Species")[45:55]
#     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species .id
#  1:          5.1         3.8          1.9         0.4     setosa  45
#  2:          4.8         3.0          1.4         0.3     setosa  46
#  3:          5.1         3.8          1.6         0.2     setosa  47
#  4:          4.6         3.2          1.4         0.2     setosa  48
#  5:          5.3         3.7          1.5         0.2     setosa  49
#  6:          5.0         3.3          1.4         0.2     setosa  50
#  7:          7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor   1
#  8:          6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor   2
#  9:          6.9         3.1          4.9         1.5 versicolor   3
# 10:          5.5         2.3          4.0         1.3 versicolor   4
# 11:          6.5         2.8          4.6         1.5 versicolor   5
```

---

Under the hood, it's essentially along the lines of:

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(iris)[, ID := sequence(.N), by = Species]
```

Or if you prefer "dplyr":

```
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  mutate(ID = sequence(n()))
```

Comment: Haven't tried but probably `row_number()` for `dplyr`. Also awfully feels like a huge dupe